# proving $1 + a + a^2 + \cdots + a^{h-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck with this problem . How can I prove that if $a\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, then $1 + a + a^2 + \cdots + a^{h-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. where p does not divide a and h is the order of a. Can the Euler Fermat theorem help ?

Comment: Yes, it helps. Multiply with $a-1$.

Comment: Have any formulas for things like $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{h-1}$?

Comment: @daniel i am not understanding how multiplying with a-1 helps . i want to reduce the series and show it is congruent to 0 mod p

Comment: It's a geometric sum. Have you tried computing $(a-1)(a^{h-1} + a^{h-2} + \dotsc + a+1)$?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595923/i-suppose-a-m-a-1-m-1-show-that-1aa2-ldotsa-phim-1-equiv0-pmod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1+a+\cdots +a^{h-1}=\frac{a^h-1}{a-1}$ .
But $p|a^h-1$ (since $h$ is the order of $a$) and $p$ does not divide $a-1$.
So, $p|\frac{a^h-1}{a-1}$ which means that the sum is $\equiv 0(modp)$